# TypeScript Error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hello I am getting a TypeScript error object is possibly undefined for
This is for given an array of pairs representing the teams that have competed against each other an array containing the results of each competition, write a function that returns the winner of the tournament. Comeptitions array has the elemtns in form of [hometeam, awayteam] the second array results 1 means the home team won and 0 means the away team won

```
    if (scoreTracker!.get(teamWhoWon) > scoreTracker!.get(currentWinningTeam)) {
  currentWinningTeam = teamWhoWon
}


This is for an algorithm data challenge of this whole function::

    export function tournamentWinner(competitions: string[][], results: number[]) {
  // Write your code here.
  let currentWinningTeam = "";

  const scoreTracker: Map<string, number>= new Map();
  scoreTracker?.set(currentWinningTeam, 0)
  // since comeptitions and results have same length, use for loop to go through both of the arrays
  // they are in order of results to comeptitionns
  // use hash map to keep track of eachTeams points
  // final loop to find the team with the higest points
  // TIME COMPLEXITY O(N) = linear 1 loop.
  // if i had 2 loops O(N^2) = quadratic
  // SPACE COMPLEXITY O(K) = memory you created
  for (const index in competitions) {

    const result: number = results[index];
    // 0 0 1
    // console.log(result);

    // ["HTML", "C#"] C# > HTML
    const [homeTeam, awayTeam] = competitions[index];

    // console.log(index);
    // #C, Python, Python
    const teamWhoWon: string = result === 0 ? awayTeam : homeTeam;

    console.log('teamwhowon', teamWhoWon)

    updateScores(teamWhoWon, 3, scoreTracker)
    console.log('scoreTracker', scoreTracker)

    if (scoreTracker!.get(teamWhoWon) > scoreTracker!.get(currentWinningTeam)) {
      currentWinningTeam = teamWhoWon
    }
  }
  return currentWinningTeam;
}

function updateScores(teamWhoWon: string, points: number, scoreTracker: Map<string, number>) {
  if (!scoreTracker?.has(teamWhoWon)) {
    scoreTracker?.set(teamWhoWon, 3)
  } else {
    scoreTracker?.set(teamWhoWon, scoreTracker?.get(teamWhoWon) + points)
  }
}

console.log(
  tournamentWinner(
    [
      ['HTML', '#C'],
      ['#C', 'Python'],
      ['Python', 'HTML'],
    ],
    [0, 0, 1]
  )
);
```

I am new to TypeScript and I'm not sure why I am getting this error. I've defined all my variables.

Comment: Is TypeScript showing the line on which the error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing is that you could add `as Type` when working with values.
For example `(scoreTracker.get(teamWhoWon) as number)`.

You could help with definition of type which returns your Map. Please consider such edits:

```js
//  if (scoreTracker!.get(teamWhoWon) > scoreTracker!.get(currentWinningTeam)) {
//   currentWinningTeam = teamWhoWon
// }


// This is for an algorithm data challenge of this whole function::

    export function tournamentWinner(competitions: string[][], results: number[]) {
  // Write your code here.
  let currentWinningTeam = "";

  const scoreTracker: Map<string, number>= new Map();
  scoreTracker.set(currentWinningTeam, 0)
  // since comeptitions and results have same length, use for loop to go through both of the arrays
  // they are in order of results to comeptitionns
  // use hash map to keep track of eachTeams points
  // final loop to find the team with the higest points
  // TIME COMPLEXITY O(N) = linear 1 loop.
  // if i had 2 loops O(N^2) = quadratic
  // SPACE COMPLEXITY O(K) = memory you created
  for (const index in competitions) {

    const result: number = results[index];
    // 0 0 1
    // console.log(result);

    // ["HTML", "C#"] C# > HTML
    const [homeTeam, awayTeam] = competitions[index];

    // console.log(index);
    // #C, Python, Python
    const teamWhoWon: string = result === 0 ? awayTeam : homeTeam;

    console.log('teamwhowon', teamWhoWon)

    updateScores(teamWhoWon, 3, scoreTracker)
    console.log('scoreTracker', scoreTracker)

    if ((scoreTracker.get(teamWhoWon) as number) > (scoreTracker.get(currentWinningTeam) as number)) {
      currentWinningTeam = teamWhoWon
    }
  }
  return currentWinningTeam;
}

function updateScores(teamWhoWon: string, points: number, scoreTracker: Map<string, number>) {
  if (!scoreTracker?.has(teamWhoWon)) {
    scoreTracker?.set(teamWhoWon, 3)
  } else {
    scoreTracker?.set(teamWhoWon, (scoreTracker?.get(teamWhoWon) as number) + points)
  }
}

console.log(
  tournamentWinner(
    [
      ['HTML', '#C'],
      ['#C', 'Python'],
      ['Python', 'HTML'],
    ],
    [0, 0, 1]
  )
);
```

Comment: sorry. can you elaborate what the "as" keyword does? and why it was the solution to my error?

Comment: you can use a type assertion to specify a more specific type as you know the format of you Map key, values
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions